# HTTP response code, response time, response length missing in Node.js / Express console output

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've got a little app that takes a request route in Node.js using Express, for example:

`http://192.168.0.10:3000/db/`

Here, /db/ is the route.  This is fine, I have a db.js file that runs, it makes a call to a MySQL server that is *expected* to take a long time (possibly minutes) to return the results of a large join.  Everything is okay if I make just a few requests now and then because I modified my settings for acceptable timeouts.  I get results like the following on the Node.js console:

`GET /db/ 200 88569.341 ms - 89`

All gravy.  However, now I'm using Apache Bench (I know it is not popular with everyone) to hammer the Node.js server and see what happens when I try and make lots of requests to the MySQL server (which is on a separate machine).  If I use this technique to increase concurrent requests through Node.js to the MySQL server (on a separate machine), I start intermittently getting the following:

`GET /db/ - - ms - -`

I don't know what this means or how to use it, but I believe it means something bad is happening, because the time taken for a test run drops by 2/3 or so (~700 seconds to ~400 seconds or thereabouts) and console logging I added in my code is *not* being output enough times to indicate that every request is being serviced.  Any tips on how to debug this to find out why some requests seem to be failing?

Note: the MySQL package I'm using is `mysql`, but I'm thinking that's not where the problem lies.

In case it helps, here is the code for my route.  As a reminder, this code works at low concurrency.  It also works without errors if I make the requests through Apache/PHP instead of Node.js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // The code below borrowed in part from the NPM MySQL package documentation at:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:/* my host */,
    user:/* username */,
    password:/* password */,
    database:/* my db name */
  });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query({sql:/* some huge join query */;',timeout:999999}, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      var output = "error! " + err;
      console.log(output);
      res.send(output);
    }
    else {
      var output = "good: " + JSON.stringify(rows);
      console.log(output);
      res.send(output);
    }
  });

  connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I think folks are going to need to see your Express code to have any idea where to look.

Comment: Agreed, was just adding it as your comment arrived.

Comment: My guess is that you run out of database connections under load.  You may have an error on `connection.connect()` which you do not have any error handling or logging for.

Comment: I increased my `max_connections` in MySQL to 100,000 just to be absolutely sure, and I'm only trying 32 concurrent requests.  I did run into that issue in earlier attempts and that's how I knew to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 tip to debug heavy load is to make sure ALL possible error paths are handled and logged.  `connection.connect()` and `connection.end()` both take callbacks that could report errors.  And, just because you set one connection limit to 100,000 does not mean you've removed all limits on how many simultaneous connections the system might allow.   There are often many different levels that limits may occur all the way from the library you are using to how it sits on the underlying OS.

I'd suggest that you create more robust logging so you can see if every request that started actually finished and to make sure all possible error paths have logging.  When this runs, you should see "Matched requestCntrs" as one of the last log entries.  If not, then some operation did not complete properly and an error was not logged.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var requestCntrStart = 0;
var requestCntrDone = 0;
var requestCntrErr = 0;

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // The code below borrowed in part from the NPM MySQL package documentation at:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
  ++requestCntrStart;
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:/* my host */,
    user:/* username */,
    password:/* password */,
    database:/* my db name */
  });

  // log any other errors
  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    ++requestCntrErr;
    console.log("Uncaught connection error: ", err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
    logMatch();
  });

  function logMatch() {
    if (requestCntrStart !== (requestCntrDone + requestCntrErr)) {
        console.log("Unmatched requestCntrs: requestCntrStart = " + requestCntrStart + 
            ", requestCntrDone = " + requestCntrDone + ", requestCntrErr = " + requestCntrErr);
    } else {
        console.log("Matched requestCntrs");
    }
  }

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      ++requestCntrErr;
      console.log("connection.connect() error: ", err);
      logMatch();
    }
  });

  connection.query({sql: 'some huge join query',timeout:999999}, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      ++requestCntrErr;
      var output = "connection.query() error! " + err;
      console.log(output);
      res.send(output);
      logMatch();
    }
    else {
      ++requestCntrDone;
      res.send(output);
      logMatch();
    }
  });

  connection.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      ++requestCntrErr;
      console.log("connection.end() error: ", err);
      logMatch();
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```